# How to get the difference in minutes between two timestamps excluding weekends?

Tags: postgresql, date-arithmetic

I need to get the difference in minutes excluding weekends (Saturday, Sunday), between 2 timestamps in postgres, but I'm not getting the expected result.

**Examples:**

Get diff in minutes, however, weekends are include

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (NOW() - '2021-08-01 08:00:00') / 60)::BIGINT as diff_in_minutes;
```

*$ diff_in_minutes = 17566*

Get diff in weekdays, excluding saturday and sunday

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as diff_in_days
 FROM generate_series('2021-08-01 08:00:00', NOW(), interval '1d') d
 WHERE extract(isodow FROM d) < 6;
```

*$ diff_in_days = 10*

**Expected:**

- From '2021-08-12 08:00:00' to  '2021-08-13 08:00:00' = 1440
- From '2021-08-13 08:00:00' to  '2021-08-16 08:00:00' = 1440
- From '2021-08-13 08:00:00' to  '2021-08-17 08:00:00' = 2880

and so on ...

Comment: What shall be the result if timestamp 1 or timestamp 2 are in weekend days?

Comment: It should be 0, if timestamp 1 is Saturday and timestamp 2 is Sunday.

If timestamp 1 is '2021-08-13 08:00:00' and timestamp 2 is '2021-08-16 08:00:00' I expect to receive 1440(Diff in Minutes)between these timestamps.

Answer (score 1):

the solution is:

```sql
SELECT GREATEST(COUNT(*) - 1, 0)
 FROM generate_series(from_ts, to_ts, interval'1 minute') AS x
WHERE extract(isodow FROM x) <= 5
```

so

```sql
SELECT GREATEST(COUNT(*) - 1, 0)
 FROM generate_series('2021-08-13 08:00:00'::timestamp, '2021-08-17 08:00:00', '1 minute') AS x
WHERE extract(isodow FROM x) <= 5
```

returns 2880

Comment: fixed to return 0 if two timestamps are inside one weekend

Comment: I think that this is by far the best one. You may generalize it into a reusable function that can skip non-working hours too.

Comment: The smaller (more granular) time intervals you use (e.g. minutes instead of days) for `generate_series` - the worse performance you will get. Especially when you use timestamps too distant from each other.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an optimal solution - but I will leave finding the optimal solution as a homework for you.

First, create an SQL function

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.time_overlap (
  b_1 timestamptz,
  e_1 timestamptz,
  b_2 timestamptz,
  e_2 timestamptz
)
RETURNS interval AS
$body$
SELECT GREATEST(interval '0 second',e_1 - b_1 - GREATEST(interval '0 second',e_1 - e_2) - GREATEST(interval '0 second',b_2 - b_1));
$body$
LANGUAGE 'sql'
IMMUTABLE
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
SECURITY INVOKER
PARALLEL SAFE
COST 100;
```

Then, call it like this:

```sql
WITH frame AS (SELECT generate_series('2021-08-13 00:00:00', '2021-08-17 23:59:59', interval '1d') AS d)
SELECT SUM(EXTRACT(epoch FROM time_overlap('2021-08-13 08:00:00', '2021-08-17 08:00:00',d,d + interval '1 day'))/60) AS total
FROM  frame
WHERE extract(isodow FROM d) < 6
```

In the CTE you should round down the left/earlier of the 2 timestamps and round up the right/later of the 2 timestamps. The idea is that you should generate the series over whole days - not in the middle of the day.

When calling the `time_overlap` function you should use the exact values of your 2 timestamps so that it properly calculates the overlapping in minutes between each day of the generated series and the given timeframe between your 2 timestamps.

In the end, when you sum over all the overlappings - you will get the total number of minutes excluding the weekends.

Comment: I wonder if `time_overlap` is already available as a builtin method of timestamp ranges

Comment: @Bergi There is `OVERLAPS` [operator](https://database.guide/how-to-test-for-overlapping-dates-in-postgresql/) but it returns Boolean rather than integer number of seconds.

Comment: I was rather thinking of the [`*` intersection operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html) on two [`tstzrange`s](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-BUILTIN) - but it seems converting the resulting range to an `interval` (to extract the minutes) [is not exactly simple](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/52153/188406) (or available as a builtin).

Comment: @Bergi Well, you can simply subtract the lower bound of the range (the result of the intersection operator is a `tstzrange`) from the upper bound of the range to get an `interval` type of value. You can create an SQL function for this, as explained in the [Wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Extract_days_from_range_type).

Comment: Yes, sure you can do that (as I've linked to), but it does require creating an SQL function which I was trying to avoid, to rely only on builtins. You can also inline that in the query, but then it's no longer simple :-)

Comment: @Bergi SQL functions are designed to hide the complexity for you - so you can use just simple queries :))